# What is the excel formula for within the next 7 business days?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight cells that contain dates that are within the next 7 weekdays. I understand I should use WORKDAY but I'm not sure what the exact formula should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want 7 business days from today, exclusive of today, (`TODAY()`) so your target date is:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),7)
```

---

If you want to know if a date is 7 days within your target date, it should be less than the output of above equation and also greater than current date, so:

```
=AND(A1>=TODAY(), A1 < WORKDAY(TODAY(),7))
```

---

*Sponsored by @Scott Craner*

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dates in cells A1 and A2, and you want to know if A2 is within the 7 working days after A1, then you can use this formula:

```
=AND(A1<=A2, WORKDAY(A1,7)<=A2)
```

The first part confirms that A2 is not *before* A1, and the second part compares A2 against 7 workdays after A1

Alternatively, you cause use `NETWORKDAYS` to work the difference between the dates, like so:

```
=AND(A1<=A2, NETWORKDAYS(A1,A2)<=7)
```